# Separating mySQL server from LAMP and performance degradation

Tags: mysql, lamp

I'm currently using LAMP stack (over Centos 6.5) for our sites, and I want to try separating the mySQL from the "web server".

Until now I was using DigitalOcean's VPS with quad core CPU and 8GB of RAM.
Yesterday I've created a new DigitalOcean VPS for a single staging environment (at the moment) with the following specs and utils:

- 2 CPU cores
- 2GB RAM
- Centos 6.7
- Private network with the "web server" (Ping time: `min/avg/max/mdev = 0.352/0.481/0.662/0.073 ms`
- mySQL 5.6 (same as it was on the current server)
- Same my.cnf configuration with 2 changes:

  1. Added: `bind-address=X.X.X.X` (the private network's internal IP address)
  2. Changed innodb_buffer_pool_size from 2GB to 1GB (because we have less RAM now..)

The web server is running a Drupal site, and has APCu, opCACHE and memcached installed.

When checking the load time with Chrome it seems that the site is now being loaded slower in about 0.5 - 1.5 sec.
Unfortunately NewRelic proves me right (see the attached screenshot)

[image]

Since this is the first time I'm configuration a remote mySQL server, I'm wondering if this is something I've missed? any configuration or adjustment that may improve the performance?

Comment: By running your system with a separate web server and database server, you have made your system *less* reliable.  Now, you need *two* servers to work.  If *either one* goes down, your entire system is down.  With both the web server and database running on one server, you only need one server.  It's not the same as owning two cars, where if *either* one works you can drive somewhere.  It's more like the tires on *one* car - if *any* tire is flat, you can't drive the car until you fix it.

Comment: And I gained scalability, security.. Not sure what's your point..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, and I think that the way I've gone through may be helpful to others.

- Check the latency between the servers using `ping`, `mtr` and `traceroute` to find out if the problem is latency related
- Check the server's load and free RAM, using `top` (or `htop`) and `free -m`
- Run heavy query on both mysql servers (old local and the new remote) and compare the query time, we may also use mySQL's profiling - see [`SHOW PROFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html)
- Assuming that the mysql query time is similar (or at least almost similar), then we may use PHP snippet to run the same code and see maybe the bottleneck is PHP related - I recommend using [NewRelic PHP application profiling](https://newrelic.com/sp/php-monitoring) - in my case, this was the "enlightenment", since eventually I saw that the problem was not even related to the remote mySQL, but the extra 0.5-1.5 seconds were caused by an additional call to a 3rd party service (only when using the remote DB..)
- Use [mysqltuner.pl](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) (as @Shahriar Shojib) suggested, and find if there are some mySQL configuration tweaks that we must have (none on my case..)
- Try disabling iptables or any other firewall
- Check the network traffic (I used `iptraf` and our 3rd party monitoring services), but there are some other options as @Julie Pelletier suggested

**Extra performance boost when using remote mySQL server**

- Use memcached, APCu and Opcode caching (although all those were already installed on our case - those are game changers..)
- Last but not least - Use SSH tunnel instead of direct connection to the mySQL server (seems like it's saving about 200 ms on the overall page load time)

Hope that reading this answer will save you more than 0.5 to 1.5 seconds :)

Comment: This point of your's got me curious: Last but not least - Use SSH tunnel instead of direct connection to the mySQL server (seems like it's saving about 200 ms on the overall page load time)  Are you sure?

Comment: No and yes.. :) I've made lot of tests and it did seem to make a different as I wrote. I'm not sure if this was a coincidence, but it does sound reasonable because the connection stays open between the two servers (am I wrong with my line of thinking?). I can make even more tests to verify this saying if you don't think this is reasonable.

Comment: I know that PHP normaly does not keep persistent connections, but with ssh you are adding another layer and crypto, so yes, just do some other test :)

Comment: >  not least - Use SSH tunnel instead of direct connection to the mySQL server (seems like it's saving about 200 ms on the overall page load time)

Probably some MTU problems cause direct connection deceleration.

Comment: @Selivanov Pavel - any way to verify your thought?

Comment: @Rotem ping -s N won't work over SSH, so onlyway I see is save similar sessions over ssh and direct with tcpdump and check difference in Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd be surprised since your MySQL server has less RAM assigned to it, and placing it on a different machine adds load on the network interface.

You should monitor your network activity to see if it causes any kind of bottleneck.

Depending on your SQL queries and PHP scripts, there could possibly be ways to better optimize those tasks in terms of query performance as well as improving the results sent back to PHP to reduce the network load.

Comment: I have no problem to increase the amount of RAM if you think that it may cause the performance degradation, but since this server holds only one staging environment at the moment, and it has ~ 1300 MB free RAM, I'm not sure if this is the problem. Any ideas how to monitor the network activity?

Comment: There are quite a few but I like `iptraf-ng`.

Comment: Great, I installed it, but what should I look for when searching for bottlenecks? Can you think of a way to find out if the problem is with the TTFB or with the mySQL server?

Comment: Start by checking the traffic generated by a single page load both on the client and DB sides.

Comment: I see traffic, but I can't find anything strange..

Comment: The question is how much traffic?  I don't expect it to be strange.

Answer (score 1):

A Few Things I will recommend:
Verify if the website is utilizing Memcached/APC/opcode caching.
I would recommend Memcached for DB query caching.
Do a few tweaks on Mysql configuration using [mysqltuner.pl](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl)

Optimize memcached apc configuration
Memcached configuration file location in Debian/Ubuntu based OS:

> /etc/memcached.conf

Memcached Configuration file in Centos/RHEL based OS:

> /etc/sysconfig/memcached

Apc configuration can be inserted in php.ini.

Following these steps should definitely increase performance.
And use NewRelic APM to reveal data about where time is being spent.
If the networking is an issue I guess there's nothing you can do about it.
Let me know.
Thanks,
Shahriar

Comment: Memcached, APCu and opcode are already installed, but to be honest memcached is installed with its default configuration. I also ran mysqltuner.pl and it didn't suggest anything that I haven't already tried. But I'm not quite sure where is the problem at the moment, is it PHP? mysql? hardware? network?